# Nebensatz mit "zwar...aber"

Tags: sentence-structure

1)

> ich glaube, dass **zwar** diese lebensweise nicht gesund ist,  **aber**  ist es ab und zu populär

2)

> ich glaube, dass **zwar** diese lebensweise nicht gesund ist, ist es **aber**
>   ab und zu populär

Können Sie bitte mir Erläutern, welcher Satz der richtige ist und warum?

Comment: Weder, noch, würde ich sagen. "..., aber es ab und zu populär ist". Satzstellung so, weil es immer noch der dass-Satz ist

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Yep. Stimme zu. Beide Sätze sind komisch. Würde niemand so sagen oder schreiben.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ich glaube, das Problem liegt in der Verwechslung von **koordinierenden** und **subordinierenden** Konjunktionen.

Mit subordinierender Konjunktion erhält man einen Nebensatz, der am Anfang eines Hauptsatzes stehen kann, wie in diesem Beispiel:

> [**Obwohl** diese Lebensweise nicht gesund **ist**], ist sie populär.

Oder mit "doppelter Einbettung": Ein Nebensatz in einem Nebensatz.

> Ich glaube, [**dass** diese Lebensweise populär **ist**, [**obwohl** sie nicht gesund **ist**.]]

**Aber** (mit oder ohne **zwar**) ist eine koordinierende Konjunktion. Im folgenden Beispiel verbindet sie zwei Hauptsätze:

> [Diese Lebensweise ist (zwar) ungesund], **aber** [sie ist populär].
>
> *Variante*:
>   Diese Lebensweise ist (zwar) [ungesund], **aber** [populär].

Oder mit Nebensätzen:

> Ich glaube, [*dass* diese Lebensweise (zwar) ungesund *ist*], **aber** [*dass* sie populär *ist*.]
>
> *Varianten*:
>   Ich glaube, *dass* diese Lebensweise (zwar) ungesund *ist*, **aber** populär.
>   Ich glaube, *dass* diese Lebensweise (zwar) ungesund, **aber** populär *ist*.

Answer (score 3):

Beide Sätze sind strukturell (aber auch orthografisch) nicht korrekt. Die Gegensätze sind die Phrasen „nicht gesund“ und „ab und zu populär“. Das Wort *zwar* leitet den einen, das Wort *aber* den anderen ein. Richtig wäre demnach:

> Ich glaube, dass diese Lebensweise <sub>⌊</sub>zwar nicht gesund<sub>⌋</sub> , <sub>⌊</sub>aber ab und zu populär<sub>⌋</sub> ist.

Allerdings empfinde ich „ab und zu populär“ als merkwürdig, da es so klingt, als würde die Popularität ständig schwanken. Ich würde es durch etwas anderes ersetzen:

> Ich glaube, dass diese Lebensweise zwar nicht gesund, aber (recht/ häufig/ bei Vielen/ ...) populär ist.

Wenn das Verb „ist“ ebenfalls zu dem einen Gegensatz gehören soll, dann muss auch ein Verb zu dem anderen Gegensatz gehören:

> > Ich glaube, dass diese Lebensweise <sub>⌊</sub>zwar nicht gesund ist<sub>⌋</sub> , (dass sie) <sub>⌊</sub>aber ab und zu populär wird<sub>⌋</sub>.

Nach meinem Gefühl kann man „dass sie“ weglassen, weshalb ich es in Klammern gesetzt habe.

Comment: Gute Antwort. Erklärt aber [diese Nachfrage](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/53059/nebensatz-mit-zwar-aber#comment128988_53060) ebensowenig, von der grammatikalischen Ebene her.

Answer (score 1):

Beide Beispielsätze sind grammatikalisch falsch. Das Problem ist die Stellung von *ist es*.

Korrigiert man diese wie folgt

1.

> > ich glaube, dass zwar diese Lebensweise nicht gesund ist, aber **es ist** ab und zu populär

2.

> > ... dass zwar diese Lebensweise nicht gesund ist, **es ist** aber ab und zu populär

Sind beide Sätze korrekt. Es hat nichts mit ***zwar*** und ***aber*** zu tun.

---

Sollte sich ***es*** nicht auf ein zuvor beschriebenes Verhalten beziehen, sondern direkt auf *die Lebensweise*, sollte besser ***sie*** (feminin) gewählt werden:

1.

> > ich glaube, dass zwar diese Lebensweise nicht gesund ist, aber **sie ist** ab und zu populär

2.

> > ... dass zwar diese Lebensweise nicht gesund ist, **sie ist** aber ab und zu populär

Comment: Ich habe deine Antwort verstanden aber ich habe nur eine Frage und zwar, warum Sie "ist" auf diese Weise gestellt haben? Sollte es nicht "dass...verb,verb..." sein. Ich meine wie "dass zwar diese Lebensweise nicht gesund ist, ist sie aber ab und zu populär"

Comment: @Max Ich bin leider kein Grammatik Experte, ich kann nur sagen (als native speaker), dass _ist es_ oder _ist sie_ die falsche Stellung ist.

Comment: Der Satz nach dem letzten Komma ist ein Hauptsatz, daher muss das Verb an der 2. Stelle stehen. *Aber* kann einem Satz vorangestellt werden und zählt dann nicht als Satzteil, daher ist ", aber sie ist..." ebenfalls korrekt.

Comment: @RHa Das muss in meinem intuitiven Sprachverständnis so tief verankert sein, dass ich es grammatikalisch nicht auflösen kann. Danke für die Erklärung.